# Azure Devops Failing on npm install (Cannot find module 'Selenium-Webdriver'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, npm-install

I am trying to integrate Selenium IDE with Azure devops test plan

I have an "NPM install" task in my release pipeline and received an error of Error: `Npm failed with return code: 1`

This is the error from the log:

```
    2020-10-12T22:37:37.9680875Z [command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" test"
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6366869Z 
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6367643Z > ind@1.0.0 test D:\a\r1\a\Test_IND-CI \drop\Selenium IDE
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6368107Z > npx mocha --reporter xunit > result.xml
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6368363Z 
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6368738Z npx: installed 136 in 32.857s
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6368973Z 
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6369245Z Error: Cannot find module 'selenium-webdriver'
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6369465Z Require stack:
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6369714Z - D:\a\r1\a\Test_IND-CI \drop\Selenium IDE\test.js
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6370004Z - C:\npm\cache\_npx\5920\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6370300Z - C:\npm\cache\_npx\5920\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6370850Z - C:\npm\cache\_npx\5920\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\one-and-dones.js
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6371232Z - C:\npm\cache\_npx\5920\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\options.js
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6371553Z - C:\npm\cache\_npx\5920\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6371883Z     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6372236Z     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6372757Z     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6373259Z     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6373925Z     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\a\r1\a\Test_IND-CI \drop\Selenium IDE\test.js:2:37)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6374606Z     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6374983Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6375320Z     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6375644Z     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6375999Z     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6382142Z     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6382865Z     at Object.exports.requireOrImport (C:\npm\cache\_npx\5920\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:20:12)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6385244Z     at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (C:\npm\cache\_npx\5920\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:33:34)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6385856Z     at Mocha.loadFilesAsync (C:\npm\cache\_npx\5920\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:427:19)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6387258Z     at singleRun (C:\npm\cache\_npx\5920\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:156:15)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6388582Z     at exports.runMocha (C:\npm\cache\_npx\5920\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:225:10)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6389265Z     at Object.exports.handler (C:\npm\cache\_npx\5920\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:366:11)
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6390655Z     at C:\npm\cache\_npx\5920\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:241:49
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6391922Z npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6590665Z ##[warning]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory
    2020-10-12T22:38:16.6612445Z ##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
```

This is the settings of my npm install task:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve "Cannot find module" error using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js)

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score -1):

> Azure Devops Failing on npm install (Cannot find module 'Selenium-Webdriver'

According to the error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'selenium-webdriver'
```

And the configuration screenshot of the build definition, we could to know that you execute the `npm test` directly without the packages. we need to use npm install command line to ensure that all the packages are installed:

`npm install selenium-webdriver --save` or `npm install`

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55392647/npm-error-cannot-find-module-selenium-webdriver-lib-input) for some more details.